# Extending Javascript syntax highlighting in vim

Tags: javascript, vim, syntax-highlighting

I would like to extend my JS syntax highlighting with highlight certain functions that will be commonly used in my program. I am using [janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) to keep all my plugins in order. Right now I have a file in there called `vim-chino` and then in there I have a `syntax` folder and a `ftdetect` folder. In both I have a `chino.vim` file. This is my `syntax/chino.vim` file:

```
if !exists("main_syntax")
  if version < 600
  syntax clear
elseif exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif
let main_syntax = 'javascript'
endif


syn match chinoKeywords "ChinoView"
hi def link chinoKeywords Function


let b:current_syntax = "javascript"
if main_syntax == 'javascript'
  unlet main_syntax
endif
```

and in my `ftdetect/chino.vim` I have:

```
function! s:DetectJS()
    if getline(1) =~# '^#!.*/bin/env\s\+node\>'
        setfiletype javascript
    endif
endfunction
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * call s:DetectJS()
```

I would like it to highlight `ChinoView` in any javascript file. I feel like the syntax highlighting for JS is either overriding it or it this is not being read.

**EDIT:** If I had to guess where something was happening was that when it looks at `b:current_syntax` it already has a syntax so it quits.

Comment: Can you check to see if `:syn list chinoKeywords` outputs anything. If it doesn't it means that your syn match isn't taking effect.

Comment: Yea it says that `No such highlight group name: chinoKeywords`. I have also tried `syn keyword chinoKeywords ChinoView` but that doesn't work  either.

Comment: Can you try just adding `syn match chinoKeywords "ChinoView"` and 
`hi def link chinoKeywords Function` to `s:DetectJS()` instead of your `syntax/chino.vim`. (after the `setfiletype javascript`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ftplugin/chino.vim` sets the syntax to `javascript`, but the extra highlighting you've defined is for the new *chino* syntax. That doesn't fit together.

If you just want an extra keyword highlighted in *all* Javascript, you can just let the default Vim detection happen and add those lines to `after/syntax/javascript.vim` (you may have to create this directory and file):

```
syn match chinoKeywords "ChinoView"
hi def link chinoKeywords Function
```

However, if you want to define a different *chino* filetype depending on the file's shebang line, you need to `:setfiletype chino` in your `ftplugin/chino.vim`, and then include the default javascript syntax in your `syntax/chino.vim` (after the initial checks, before you set `b:current_syntax`):

```
runtime! syntax/javascript.vim syntax/javascript/*.vim
```

Comment: I am already using a plugin to extend my javascript highlighting. Is there anyway to add additional highlighting without editing that plugin's `.vim` file?

Comment: As I said, `~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim` is sourced after the original syntax script. Try putting your additions there.

Comment: Since I am using Janus all I had to do was make a syntax folder in my vim-chino folder and name is `javascript.vim` and just have the:

`syn match chinoKeywords "ChinoView"`
`hi def link chinoKeywords Function`

in there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad you've found a solution! Many people dislike distributions like _Janus_ because of its added complexities.